# Can't find my Mac last location even if my Mac was online only for half an hour?

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

My Mac was lost the other night. Someone probably wiped it clean, and reset nvram.

Is it possible to see last locations on Find my Mac?

Because who ever found it, he must have been connected to Wifi for at least 15-20min so he can do what he has done.

So the question is: can I see more than one last location of my MacBook, when he was online, on Find my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how smart the 'finder' was.

If they were fully aware of how to deal with a <strike>stolen</strike> ermm... *borrowed* computer, & knew to take it well away from any potential location-capable resource, then it could have been wiped with no further data exchange & therefore no Find My Mac information.

Unlike an iPhone/iPad. a computer is not a completely locked-down environment, unless the drive is encrypted with [FileVault](https://support.apple.com/HT204837) & a [firmware password](https://support.apple.com/HT204455) set - though you still need to have enabled [Find My Mac](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html).

Comment: the drive wasnt encrypted with filevault and no pass..so i probably cant do anything, except found last location when it was online. so is it possible to see multiple locations if he first connect it at home, and after that at siome wifi caffe..?

Comment: You can only see the last location it connected from - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2698